# Replace value of one column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames named `df` and `df_reference`, which contain following information:

```
df                  df_reference
col1  col2          col1 col2
 A     10            A    15
 B     25            B    33
 C     30            C    20
 A     12
```

I want to compare both data frame based on `col1`.
I want to replace the value of `df.col2` with `df_reference.col2` if the value in `df_reference` is greater than value of `df.col2`.

The expected output is:

```
df                  
col1  col2         
 A     15            
 B     33           
 C     30           
 A     15
```

I have tried:

```
dict1 = {'a':'15'}
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(dict1.keys()), 'col2'] = sams['col1'].map(dict1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and NaNs if some values are not matched are replace by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df['col1'].map(df_reference.set_index('col1')['col2']).fillna(df['col2'])

df.loc[s > df['col2'], 'col2'] =  s
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A    15
1    B    33
2    C    30
3    A    15
```

Comment: I don't think this answers "if the value in df_reference is greater than value of df.col2", does it? Edit: no it doesn't, see row C :)

Comment: @jezrael. I dont want to replace a value if the value in df.col2 is larger than df_reference.col2

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to first do a merge based on 'col1' and then apply a function that generates a new column with the greater value of the two 'col2'. Then just drop the useless column !

```
def greaterValue(row) :
   if (row['col2_x']>row['col2_y']) :
      return row['col2_x']
   else :
      return row['col2_y']
```

`df = df.merge(df_reference, left_on='col1', right_on='col1')
df['col2'] = df.apply(greaterValue, axis=1)
df = df.loc[:,['col1','col2']]`